# My keydown event is runs too many times if i click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#news_container_inner").animate({
                // zuun
                left: (int_px($("#news_container_inner").css("left")) + 945) > 0 ? MAX_LENGTH : "+=945"
            });
            $('#dragBar').animate({
                left: (int_px($("#dragBar").css("left")) - dragBar_road) < 0 ? MAX_LENGTH_Drag+1 : "-="+dragBar_road
            });
            console.log('left');
      }
      else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#news_container_inner").animate({
          // baruun
          left: (int_px($("#news_container_inner").css("left")) - 945) < MAX_LENGTH ? 0 : "-=945"
        });
        $('#dragBar').animate({
            left: (int_px($("#dragBar").css("left")) + dragBar_road) > MAX_LENGTH_Drag+1 ? 1 : "+="+dragBar_road
        });
        console.log('right');
      }
    });
```

Here is my code. The problem is if i click right arrow button for 1 second this event runs 35 times. I need to bind it 3 or 4 times if i click for 1 second.
Sorry for bad english.
Please help me.

Comment: If you want to appear to slow down the polling rate you will need to use a timer set to either `333ms`, or `250ms` depending on whether you want 3 or 4 actions per second.

Comment: but how? I don't know what should i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with a counter if you just want to fire it e.g. 4 times:

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    counter++;

    if(counter > 4) {
        return;
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 37) { 
        console.log('left');
    } else if(e.keyCode == 39) {      
        console.log('right');
    }

}).on('keyup', function(e) {
    counter = 0;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vRhVt/1/)

**EDIT**

If you want to limit the number of events per second you can use `setInterval`:

```
var counter = 0,
    intervalInited = false;

function initInterval() { 
    intervalInited = true;

    setInterval(function(){
        if(counter > 4) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    counter++;

    if(counter > 4) {
        if(!intervalInited) {
            initInterval();
        }
        return;
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 37) { 
        console.log('left');
    } else if(e.keyCode == 39) {      
        console.log('right');
    }

}).on('keyup', function(e) {
    counter = 0;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vRhVt/2/)

Comment: This will prevent any further key press after 4, regardless i pressed the key for 1sec or 10 sec.. i think the requirement is to fire 4 key press events per sec..